# RemoteMessage.GetNotification() returns null when request is not from Firebase Console?

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin.android, httprequest, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am testing Firebase Cloud Messaging.

If I use a Firebase Console to send a message - in my code I Notification object with values set - not a problem:

```
public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        base.OnMessageReceived(message);

        Firebase.Messaging.RemoteMessage.Notification oNotification;

        oNotification = message.GetNotification();
```

I am using http://requestmaker.com/ to send a notification - and all works fine - it sends and I get back the messageID.

```
POST /fcm/send HTTP/1.1
Host: fcm.googleapis.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: key=not-a-real-key0omClYhniZaIAercMVzeFHEG508USi8lud9pxC-SzxAAbR2mflAfVNsfrbrsPJxoFYTr15ytRn9aqWSQXm5x00AOwu2Wl6mWwTcm9l6G
Content-Length: 188
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

But the `oNotification = message.GetNotification();` returns null.
The questions is - why?

Comment: Hi. There's a chance that you're sending a [`data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) payload instead of a `notification` payload. When using the Firebase Console, the message sent is always treated as a `notification` payload message. Can you post the *request data* you are sending with requestmaker?

Comment: Request URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send - Authorization key=AAAAAXu6AHE:APA9.... Request Data registration_id=eMM1bnJVxT8:APA91bEiVop08dRKLTSF9LdW4mGql8EFw9CwXjLqdAqxs7D8A_GF_D6DU7QPyy5JahzZoQVraJmxTQiV0UTUet_hbr1G_9xNv87Vpu4yCgN751hVF07hdRx-hlJRcfUEC82IlvaV-9AD

Comment: @AL. That is a good point! https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Comment: @AL. Please feel free to post it as an answer! This link really describes it the best - but one quick thing to mention here is - if you don't set a notification object (whether you are using Json or plain HTTP request) - you can't expect an object to be there for you. That is why I was seeing null when tried to access it.

Comment: Hi @AlexeyFShevelyov. I added in an answer. Feel free to add in some details that you think would be useful. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that you were sending a [`data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) payload instead of a `notification` payload. When using the Firebase Console, the message sent is always treated as a `notification` payload message (or a combination of both if you added custom key-value pairs in the Advance Options). See [FCM Message Types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages).

It's possible that you were only sending `data`-only payloads when using the requestmaker. In your code, you're only handling messages with `notification` payload types:

```
message.GetNotification();
```

I'm not fully familiar with Android Xamarin, but usually with FCM, there is also a way to get the `data` payloads by calling [`RemoteMessage.getData()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.html#getData()), should you decide to send `data`-only payloads.

Comment: We had the same issue with Vero, its default template uses the `data` object not the `notification`

Comment: Then why do I even fill out notification text on the console if it's not going to be in the message? I'm finding the "Notification Name" in the message.bundle but nothing else, messsage.getData returns {ArrayMap@18813} 0