# remoteMessage.getNotification() is always null when notification is sent from server - Android

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my project, I need to send a notification from server to client. I am able to send notifications from FCM console but when I send a notification from server to client, **remoteMessage.getNotification()** always return null. While data is received correctly. When I send both data and notification only data is a non-null while the notification is null.

I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947934/remotemessage-getnotification-returns-null-when-request-is-not-from-firebase-c) question. But the solution isn't working for me.
Below is a snippet of client and server side code along with a screenshot while debugging client app.

Client App:(onMessageReceived)

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)

    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage?.from)

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if ((remoteMessage?.data?.size ?: 0) > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Message data payload: ${remoteMessage?.data}")
    }
    val a = remoteMessage?.notification
    if (a != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.notification?.body)
    }

}
```

server side code(node.js)

```
var request = require('request');

// Set the headers
var headers = {
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'key=AIzaSyAzMLMp....'  
}

// Configure the request
var options = {
    url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    form: {
        "to": "eZoeSIRba6g:AP...",
        "notification" : { "body" : "my body"} }

}

// Start the request
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Print out the response body
        console.log(body)
    }
    console.log(body + " error : " + error)
})
```

while if I use following part then the code works fine.

```
form: {
    "to": "eZoeSIRba6g:APA91bEYrP...",
    "data" : { "body" : "my body"} }
```

Screenshot while debugging the app.(Check value of variable 'a') 
[image]

If someone has any idea of how to resolve this issue then please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think when you send your data in “notification”  , the message will be received by android notification listener and your onMessageReceived will not be called, so the getNotification() will be null.

Comment: Hi @fatemehfallahiarezoudar, I tried even this -->> `"notification":{
            "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
            "body":"great match!"
          }
        }`
from [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) but still, I am getting the result as null. Can you please tell what JSON structure should be? Thank you for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
 "to" : "YOUR_FCM_TOKEN_WILL_BE_HERE",
 "data" : {
 "body" : "First Notification",
 "title": "Collapsing A",
 "key_1" : "Data for key one",
 "key_2" : "Hellowww"
 }
}
```

Use a JSON like this , then your onMessageReceived will be called.

Comment: As I said mentioned in the question I am able to send data but not notification. Thank you for reply but I want to know how to send notifications not data.

Comment: As far as I know, when you put “notification” in your JSON the android default notification listener will receive it and you can just change the icon and color from your manifest.

Comment: [https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) as per official doc we can send notification this way but it isn't working in my case.

Comment: According to this line “Notification messages, sometimes thought of as display messages , these are handled by the FCM SDK automatically “ in the official doc you sent . Your onMessageReceived won’t be called like i said.

Comment: @MandarSadye do you have problem showing notification when you send data?

Comment: No, I can create notifications programatically. I just thought it will be good if notifications were created automatically as they are created in case of FCM notification as I won't have to deal with checking running services and other stuffs

Comment: Well as it can't be done I am creating notifications programmatically as of now. I am upvoting the answer and by tomorrow if no better answer comes then I will mark it as accepted. Thank you for the answer. I don't know how much time I would have wasted trying all sorts of things if it was not for your suggestion :)

Comment: use this library it is really easy and I don't think you would need to deal with running services and ... , (https://github.com/halysongoncalves/Pugnotification)